# Test Automation for SAP

Tags: automated-testing, fitnesse, sap

I'm evaluating a number of test automation framworks to implement on a SAP project.

Right now I'm looking at

- [Fitnesse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitnesse), which we believe we can write some fixtures for, to call SAP
- [Green Hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Hat_%28software_company%29), which has the ability to interface with SAP
- SAP Accelerator which uses HT test tool suite

Does anyone have experience they can convey in implementing an automated test suite on a SAP project or with any of the test tools I've mentioned above?

Comment: Curious, since I have no experience with SAP. What is specific about SAP applications that it requires specific testing frameworks? Specific API to access? Specific business domain? Aren't generic frameworks like SoapUI, Fitnesse sufficient?

Comment: Can you add links to SAP Accelerator ? Does it stand for SAP BI Accelerator? What HT stands for? Can you expand it and/or add a link to it?

Answer (score 3):

**For web based applications**

I think [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) should also be considered as testing tool for SAP application as most of the SAP applications are web based. This is one of the best open source web testing framework available and online support from [WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) users is awesome.

Comment: Nilesh - do you mean Selenium WebDriver? If so, could you please edit your answer to make this clear?

Answer (score 3):

great tool for SAP could be Tosca test Suite, just a bit more expensive than others. Nothing that SAP guys can't bear. In advance, there is a great Test data management and easiest automation I ever have seen. When you reconsider the sustainability of automated tests in continuous development (scripts in other automated tools should be often repaired or rewritten, but this is not how Tosca works), Tosca is a good choice.

**Update**:
Our team just successfully automated the **SAP GUI** project with a Robot Framework. We struggle a bit with old fashion `frameset`s in the beginning but finally succeed. SAP GUI is old fashion code full of tables, but on the other hand, each object has a unique ID with some rubbish numbers inside and we build a framework for each type of the GUI element, using `contains` keyword of the XPath. Fine for most implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I currently work at Worksoft and based on what you're looking for it seems that our software would be a good fit for your situation. Our test automation software is designed to test SAP business processes the way that you use them and to make sure every SAP process works – and it spans SAP’s complete family of products. This enhances user experience because the automation helps to gain efficiency and improve quality by increasing QA coverage, accelerating projects, and reducing costs.

You can see more about how we work with SAP here: https://www.worksoft.com/sap-test-automation.

If you'd like to read about the experience some of our customers have had with implementing SAP, here is a good post on that: 
https://www.worksoft.com/accenture-digitizes-sap-testing-worksoft-automation

Comment: Chris, as written, your answer is likely to be flagged as spam very quickly. Please edit to answer the OP's question about people's *experience* implementing your organization's automation software.

Comment: @KatePaulk I had the same reaction as you.  However I've looked through the website and, ignoring this promotion from an employee, this might actual be a good solution that is specific to SAP automation.  However some info from real users would certainly be very helpful here!

Comment: Chris, thanks for the edits. To be frank, the question isn't the greatest question to begin with, which makes it tough for great answers to filter through.

Comment: Sorry about that! I tried to edit for transparency and added in a few benefits that we hear from customers but I also think that we have a few blog posts about customers using Worksoft to implement SAP projects which might be helpful too so I'll add those in! Thank you for the feedback.